# Error data in chart pie highchart MVC ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts

I'm having trouble generating a pie chart in the style of Highcharts.  I have the following code to generate the series

```
        if (vlrTot1 >= 0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            aSeries["data"] = new List<object[]>();
            aSeries["name"] = "TIR <= " + vlrLimInf.ToString();

            object[] values = new object[2];
            decimal vlr1 = Math.Round(((vlrTot1 / (vlrTot1 + vlrTot2 + vlrTot3)) * 100), 1);
            values[0] = "TIR <= " + vlrLimInf.ToString();
            values[1] = vlr1;
            ((List<object[]>)aSeries["data"]).Add(values);
            dataResult.Add(aSeries);

        }
        if (vlrTot2 >= 0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            aSeries["data"] = new List<object[]>();
            aSeries["name"] = vlrLimInf.ToString() + " > TIR <= " + vlrLimSup.ToString();

            object[] values = new object[2];
            decimal vlr2 = Math.Round(((vlrTot2 / (vlrTot1 + vlrTot2 + vlrTot3)) * 100), 1);
            values[0] = vlrLimInf.ToString() + " > TIR <= " + vlrLimSup.ToString();
            values[1] = vlr2;
            ((List<object[]>)aSeries["data"]).Add(values);
            dataResult.Add(aSeries);

        }
        if (vlrTot3 >= 0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> aSeries = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            aSeries["data"] = new List<object[]>();
            aSeries["name"] = "TIR > " + vlrLimSup.ToString();

            object[] values = new object[2];
            decimal vlr3 = Math.Round(((vlrTot3 / (vlrTot1 + vlrTot2 + vlrTot3)) * 100), 1);
            values[0] = "TIR > " + vlrLimSup.ToString();
            values[1] = vlr3;
            ((List<object[]>)aSeries["data"]).Add(values);
            dataResult.Add(aSeries);

        }
```

However, this generating this graph.

[image]

The first two series of 100%.

The correct graph would have to be this:

[image]

Below is the output to generate the graph with json:

```
      var data = ServiceGraf.GetValuesByGrafPie(....PARAMETERS....);

                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In index:

```
                function (data) {
                 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            ignoreHiddenSeries: false,
                            type: graf,
                            plotBackgroundColor: null,
                            plotBorderWidth: null,
                            plotShadow: false

                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Gráfico do Levantamento de ' + levant
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            pie: {
                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                showInLegend: true
                            }
                        },
                        series: data
                    });
                   }
```

I do not know where this wrong.
Below is the output value of the Json.
[image]

[image]

Comment: In general, how your data variable looks like?

Comment: I'll edit the question and put the picture.

Comment: Could you pase as string or something? not as screenshot, because I would like to copy/paste into my example.

Comment: This in the first script, just do not put the function.

Comment: I mean something like data = [1,2,3,4,5] serialized value, which is used.

Comment: So the first script I do is an account that calculates the percentage according to the indices. My output would have to be this way: data: [['TIR <= 2', 98.0 ], ['2 > TIR <= 3', 2.0 ],['TIR > 3', 0.0 ] ]. But do not know why is not generating, but generates the first two series with 100%.I searched several examples on the internet but have not found anything like what I need. Could put an example?

Comment: @Mark could help me ?

Comment: Any errors in the console, because data seems to be fine.

Comment: So I do not know what's happening, the first two series are appearing commm 100%.